# How could I print the stack-trace of my "libxxx.so" when error occured?

Tags: android, android-ndk, stack-trace

I am trying to have my app run on my `Nexus 5(4.4.4)`.By the way, the app runs just fine on my other devices.However there is something wrong with my `"libxxx.so"`. The error message is like this:

```
invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x2d6e7459 passed to dlfree
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 4382 (Thread-15350)
```

Nothing more details.

- I have tried the **`ndk-stack`** tool, but it didn't work.

I was wondering how could I get the crash `backtrace/stack-trace` printed in the `Eclipse's` logcat or shown in other places. So that I can locate where the error is in my C code.

**Any idea how to solve this?**

Comment: Normally you would see a stack trace from the dlfree() abort in logcat, with no additional work required on your part.  It's written to the log by a system daemon, so if you're only getting your app's output you won't see it... but if you're using the logcat viewer in Eclipse it should be there.  There are some things that can prevent it from appearing, e.g. if the app crashes again while trying to handle the crash.  You may need to attach gdb.

Comment: There are not stack-trace in my Eclipse logcat indeed, which bother me so much.I never tried gdb before.Could you give me more information about "gdb"?Thank you very much.